# How do you say 'daily schedule or routine' in Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

My resource for checking whether or not a word is attested in Latin is [packhum](https://latin.packhum.org/).  I have seen three proposals for how to translate this word: 'schedula', 'defunctarius', and 'horarium' but none of these words are attested in any of the authors writing before 200 AD according to packhum.  It's quite possible that because the Romans weren't as obsessed with time as we are that they never named this concept so perhaps those aforementioned words come from the Middle Ages.

Comment: See, that's the thing with Packhum: the world, and for that matter the Roman empire, did not end in the year 200. Both *schedula* and *horarium* are very much "attested in Latin," but the first documented occurrences seem to be in Jerome and one 3rd century grammarian named Censorinus, respectively. Alas, the meanings are quite different (small leaf of paper and clock).